# Creating a data set using rnorm to simulate 200 animals and their weight?

Tags: r, ggplot2, analysis

For my studies, i have been asked to generate a data set simulating 200 mice using the rnorm() function, with the mean 20 and variation of 2. I then need to plot this data using qplot() and the denisty geom.

So far this is what i have generated but i dont know how to add identifiers to each indivdual value since when i try to plot onto a qplot() the Y axis is unlabelled and the value doesnt relate to my work.

Would anyone know how to plot this data with identifiers since i then need to combine it with another data set in future tasks?

```
micebefore = rnorm(n = 200, mean = 20, sd = sqrt(2))
```

The main issue is that it generates the correct number of values with the correct means and variation, however it is useless to analyse because there are no identifiers.

Sorry im quite new to the R language! Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

I am getting an error when trying to use the micebefore dataset and the ID numbers to plot a graph using qplot():

```
qplot(micebefore, mIDbefore, geom = "density")
```

Is returning the error:

```
# Error: geom_density requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

Comment: `id = seq_along(micebefore)`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "plot"? If you want a histogram (or a density plot) you don't need an identifier. In fact, your qplot command works if you remove the second argument entirely.

Comment: additionally, all those observations are interchangeable by definition and thus there is no point in defining an identifier prior to merging the random data into whatever dataset you have. If you're asking how to insert these observations to an existing data structure (a data.frame perhaps?), I suggest you ask that explicitly (with a reproducible example).